# ios - is there a way to set the height of a scroll view in a storyboard?

Tags: ios, scrollview

I have a screen to which I am trying to add scrolling. I am able to do command+select all elements, and then embed that in a scroll view.  But how could I set the amount of scrolling in the storyboard?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - No.

You want the [`cotentSize`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentSize) of the `UIScrollView`.  It defines the size of the scrollable area - If its bigger then its actual frame size the scroll view will scroll.

There is no way to set this on using interface builder (even with scoreboards).  I have always found this a shame.  You can now set the content insets (but that not what you want).

[image]

You can:

1. Create an IBOutlet to it in Interface Builder, then set the content Size in your view controler's view did load method. OR..
2. Create a custom subview of `UIScrollView`, which automatically sets the content size to be the size of its first subview.  (assuming the scroll view will only have one subview)

[image]